# Java Double/Integer

Tags: java, math, int, double

> ```
> int a = 1;
> int b = 10;
> int c = 3;
>
> int d = (1/10)*3
>
> System.out.println(d)
>
> Result: 0
> ```

How do i make this Calculation work ?
and round up or down ?
It should be:
(1/10)*3 = 0.1 * 3 = 0.3 = 0 and
(4/10)*3 = 0.4 * 3 = 1.2 = 1

Thanks a lot!

Comment: OP, please **accept** your answer instead of adding a message to the question. Click the grey checkmark to the left of the answer. This signals to everyone that the question is indeed answered and you are satisfied with the answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
1 / 10
```

This is integer division and as integer division the result is 0.
Then 0 * 3 = 0

You can use double literals:

```
1.0 / 10.0
```

Comment: Those are floats. To specify double append a `D`.

Comment: @SteveKuo: no, [floating-point literals are `double` by default](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2). It's *only* a `float` if you suffix it with `F` (or `f`).

Answer (score 1):

> 1/10

This line return 0.so 0*3=0.Use **double** instead of **int**

Comment: And then cast it back, or round it to int, if you need to.

Comment: This won't work - 1/10 is still integer division, so the result is 0 again (of type double)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
int d = (int) (((double)4/10)*3);
```

Answer (score 0):

as both a and b are integer so the output will also be int which makes 1/10 as 0 and then 0*3=0

Answer (score 0):

You will want to perform the calculation using floating-point representation. Then you can cast the result back to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I note that you refer in your question to *rounding up/down*.

[Math.round()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29) will help you here.

> Returns the closest long to the argument. The result is rounded to an
>   integer by adding 1/2, taking the floor of the result, and casting the
>   result to type long.

Answer (score 0):

This will works

```
int a = 1;
int b = 10;
int c = 3;    
int d = (1*3/10);    
System.out.println(d);
```