# java program using int and double

Tags: java, int, double

I have written a simple Java program as shown here:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i1 =2;
        int i2=5;
        double d = 3 + i1/i2 +2;
        System.out.println(d);
    }
}
```

Since variable `d` is declared as double I am expecting the result of this program is `5.4` but I got the output as `5.0`

Please help me in understanding this.

Comment: Incidentally, try to search before asking, just searching for java int and double gives http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008306/java-int-vs-double as its second answer and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12105494/java-double-integer as its third, both duplicates of this question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`i1/i2` will be 0. Since `i1` and `i2` are both integers.

If you have `int1/int2`, if the answer is not a perfect integer, the digits after the decimal point will be removed. In your case, `2/5` is 0.4, so you'll get 0.

You can cast `i1` or `i2` to `double` (the other will be implicitly converted)

`double d = 3 + (double)i1/i2 +2;`

Answer (score 5):

`i1/i2` when converted to int gives 0. ie. why you are getting 5.0. Try this :

```
 public static void main(String args[])
    {
            int i1 =2;
            int i2=5;
            double d = 3 + (double)i1/(double)i2 +2;
            System.out.println(d);
        }
```

Comment: +1. But you can cast only one of them, the other will be implicitly  converted.

Comment: right,I just add it to increase readability and understanding.

Answer (score 3):

This line is done in parts:

```
double d = 3 + i1/i2 +2;

double d = 3 + (i1/i2) +2;
double d = 3 + ((int)2/(int)3) +2;
double d = 3 + ((int)0) +2;
double d = (int)5;
double d = 5;
```

The double just means that the answer will be cast to a double, it doesn't have any effect till the answer is computed. You should write

```
double d = 3d + (double)i1/i2 +2d; //having one double in each "part" of the calculation will force it to use double maths, 3d and 2d are optional
```

Answer (score 2):

`i1/i2` will be 0 because both `i1` and `12` are integers.

if you cast `i1` or `i2` to `double` then it will give the desired output.

```
double d = 3 + (double)i1/i2 +2;
```

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://way2java.com/casting-operations/data-type-casting-type-conversion/) provides information about data type conversion, both implicit and explicit type.

To provide exact answer to the question will be :

```
double d = 3 + (double)i1/i2 + 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int i1 =2;
int i2=5;
double d = 3 + (double)i1/(double)i2 +2;
```

if i1/i2 will be fractional value then double will help it to be in fraction instead of int.
so now you will the result as you want. or you can also use following code 
    double d = 3+(double)i1/i2+2;
In this line i1 is converted into double which will be divided with i2 and result will be in double, so again result will be as 5.4

Answer (score 0):

Since i1=2 and i2=5 are integer type and when you divide (2/5) them, It gives integer value (0) because fractional part(.4) get discarded.
So put (double)i1/i2 on the equation.